# Round function in Feistel

Tags: block-cipher, feistel-network

Following situation. We got a Feistel network. And in each round we get following outcome on the left side:

$$L^\prime = L_1 \oplus F(K_1, R_1)$$

Is there a possible key to get an unchanged outcome if $F(K_1,R_1)=K_1\oplus R_1$?

Comment: The portion _"if $i\oplus K_1$ with $R_1$"_, thus the question, is unintelligible. Also, $L^\prime = L_1 \oplus F(K_1, R_1)$ should I guess be $L^\prime_i=L_i \oplus F(K_i, R_i)$ if that's for all rounds. If that's a homework question, what have you tried?

Comment: Hi thank you for the quick reply, what i meant was K1 xor R1. So for the first Round of the feistel: L´1=L1 xor F(K1 xor R1) .  I tried to do a truthtable for this.

Comment: Got it! Your "i Xor K1" was to be understood as "I combine $K_1$ using XOR" and got changed to $i\oplus K_1$ by a first edit attempt. That's now fixed. Try to write down what $(L_i,R_i)$ is as a function of $(L_1,R_1)$ and $K_1,\dots,K_{i−1}$, for the first few positive integers $i$, per the definition of a Feistel network with the $F$ you are using, while simplifying using associativity and commutativity of $\oplus$, and that for all $X$ and $Y$, it holds that $X\oplus X\oplus Y=Y$. Conclude.

Comment: So if I am right my own entered inputs are the keys that don’t change the output.